# Angular Firebase doesn't execute the function directly after I press a button

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

So I am creating a simple app to upload a file to Firebase Storage and then save the download URL to the Firebase Database.

The steps of the app:

1. user press a button
2. camera opened
3. user capture image and confirm the image they just capture.
4. app upload the image to the Firebase Storage
5. app get the download URL of uploaded image
6. app send/save the URL to Firebase Database

Steps 1 to 5 run without a problem. However, at step 6, the data is not stored to in the database, not until I change the view of the app. I am using Ionic by the way. And this is the code I use for Step 6.

```
var ref=FirebaseRef.child('kejadian/');
  var list = $firebaseArray(ref);
  list.$add({ 
      'lokasi':lat+','+long,
      'pelapor':userid,
      'gambar':gambar,
      'waktukejadian':timestamp
   }).then(function(ref) {
      alert("Terkirim");

      console.log("inisiasi data selesai");
  });
```

Same thing happens when I try to retrieve data from the database,
the data is retrieved (and displayed to view) only after I do something in the view (like click on the input field or something).

This is probably occurring in Ionic framework. The logic is working fine with native Android.

Is there anything wrong with my code or the  way I implemented the code?
I am new to Firebase and Angular. Any suggestion would be very appreciated.

Comment: Are you saying that the `alert` doesn't show until you change views? That sounds weird. Can you set up a minimal jsbin/jsfiddle that reproduces that behavior?

Comment: yes, that is exactly what i mean. not only the alert not showing but the data also not stored on the database. but this behaviour only accure in the ionic, work fine on the web. so i am not sure if i can set up / reproduce this on jsfiddle.

Comment: Maybe check to see if there's an error? `.then(function(ref) { ... }, function(){ /*check for error*/ })`

Comment: there is no error..
in fact, the function is working.. and .then(successCallback,errorCallback) thing is execute the first function (the success callback). its just delayed and executed only after i changed/navigate to other view.